# Is it possible to show charts on Mapbox as a marker

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I already have an example of the cluster feature and I like the donut chart that is given out. This donut however is generated based on the clustering of data of lower levels.

What I'd like to do is generate a donut, pie or bar chart based on certain fields against certain co-ordinates.

For example, if I'm referring to satisfaction

Location Happy Neutral Sad Longitude Latitude
London     5    2       6   123123   -5432

And then generate a chart based upon the Happy Neutral Sad fields, at the given co-ordinates.

Comment: I found this but it's 12 years old and I'm hoping that there's a much more simpler way to do this now;  https://medium.com/devseed/adding-pie-charts-to-map-tiles-using-svg-inkscape-and-tilecache-995136a370ef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No donut chart, but I made a sample of a line chart using Chart.min.js. and jQuery. You surely can fill the gap using donut charts available in Chart.min.js
[image]

Here is a [fiddle I have created to show you how to create a popup with a chart](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/24ykvm91/1/).

Relevant code is below.
First of all add your links to jquery and chart.js

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Then you add a canvas that will be managed by chart.js

```js
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: false })
            .setLngLat([-96, 37.8])
            .setHTML('<div class="chart"><canvas id="lineChart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas></div>')
            .addTo(map);
```

and then add the data sources, options and render the chart in the canvas

```js
   //this is fake data just for testing
   var areaChartData = {
      labels  : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label               : 'Digital Goods',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
          pointRadius          : false,
          pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
          pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          data                : [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        },
        {
          label               : 'Electronics',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointRadius         : false,
          pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data                : [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
      ]
    }

    //these are the options for testing
    var areaChartOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      responsive : true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines : {
            display : false,
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines : {
            display : false,
          }
        }]
      }
    }


    var lineChartCanvas = $('#lineChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var lineChartOptions = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartOptions)
    var lineChartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartData)
    lineChartData.datasets[0].fill = false;
    lineChartData.datasets[1].fill = false;
    lineChartOptions.datasetFill = false

    var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, { 
      type: 'line',
      data: lineChartData, 
      options: lineChartOptions
    })
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed MapBox may have had some charting built in but your solution works great and I have my Donuts :-)

Comment: Great to hear it was helpful!